# What's wrong with double in C#

Tags: c#, double

I got a code:

```
for (double i= 0; i < 1; i+=0.02)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Iteration {0}", i));
}
```

And result is:

[image: console output gives 0,xx00000000001]

I can't understand why it's add mystic 0,0000000000001?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples
Use a decimal instead of a double if you need more precission.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Nothing, that's floating point arithmetic.